# Difference between Ibovespa full and mini futures contract

Tags: futures

What is the difference between the following two Brazilian futures contracts:

1. The [Ibovespa Futures Contract](http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/contratos2/pdf/IbovespaFutures.pdf)
2. The [Mini Ibovespa Futures Contract](http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/contratos2/pdf/IND_futures_mini.pdf)

As far as I can tell, both are priced in Brazilian Real (R$) following the Bovespa Index exactly. I would have guessed the *mini* contract to be cheaper than the *full* contract, or at least different in some way.

How are the Ibovespa and Mini Ibovespa futures contracts different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futures have a value per point. According to this page, the contract point value is 1 for the normal contract and 0.2 for the smaller one (Mini):

http://www.terrafuturos.com.br/valor-dos-pontos-por-contrato_eng.php

Basically you should have the same PL if you were using 5 minis or 1 normal contract, assuming that the price of the two futures is always equal (which I do not know if it is the case).

Your documentation says that your PL is:

$$
\mathrm{\Delta{Points}} \cdot \mathrm{ValuePerPoint}
$$

$\mathrm{ValuePerPoint}$ is 1 for the large contract and 0.2 for the other.

Comment: @Randomblue: I am not sure what you mean, the values from the table (0.2 and 1) are the 'value of each point' in your formula. This is what is changing between the contracts.

Comment: what do you mean with "PL", @BlueTrin? Thanks in advance